Telebot выгрузка файлов из бота на телефон (Python)
как реализовать выгрузку apk файла?
Он находится в самом проекте бота. Нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки "скачать приложение" бот передал данный apk файл в телефон пользователя, в папку download
Библиотека Telebot - Python

Отправить как файл.‍♀️
